# Image are not visible in my site(Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

## Situation

I tried to get image cover at notion to show notion cover photo in my portfolio site.
I get cover url at query data list and show notion data base cover in my portfolio_site.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzEn9.png)

````js
import Image from "next/image";

export default function ProjectItem({data}){
    
    const Title = data.properties.Name.title[0].plain_text
    const githublink = data.properties.Github.url
    const youtubelink = data.properties.Youtube.url
    const description = data.properties.Description.rich_text[0].plain_text
    const imgSrc = data.cover.file?.url || data.cover.external.url 
    
    console.log(imgSrc)
            
            
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col p-6 m-3 bg-slate-700 rounded-md">
            
        <a>
            <Image 
                scr={imgSrc}
                width={100}
                height={60}
            />  
        </a>
            
            
            <h1>{Title}</h1>
            <h3>{description}</h3>
            <a href={githublink}>깃허브 바로가기</a>
            <a href={youtubelink}>유튜브 시연영상 보러가기</a>
        </div>
    );`
    
}```

But images are corrupted in my site like this. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUbt8.png)


## Trial1
So I attempt to modify next.config.js. I made images domain arrary.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3x2F.png)

But nothing is solved.

## Trial2
And I tried console.log to check if image source links are get in const imageSrc.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRs9F.png)

It is good to receive image source links.

What is wrong with my code? Is that I something to miss out?
````

Comment: You've added 'scr' prop to <Image /> component instead of src. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I solved this problem thanks to your feedback! It was my mistake which is typo. 
Thanks for your feedback!